# display comments on php

Tags: php, mongodb

i want to display comments with php. My database is mongodb, and this is my collection articles :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55be4a1a71dd7ecc05b7acd9"), "title" : "test", "content" : "test", "user" : "Paul", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-08-02T16:49:30.480Z"), "comments" : [ { "comment" : "this is my test", "user" : "Paul" } ], { "comment" : "my second test", "user" : "Paul" } ]  }
```

So i want display this comments : "this is my test" and "my second test"
i have this code but it don't work :

```
  <?php
       try {
           $mongodb = new MongoClient();
           $collection = $mongodb->blog->articles;
         } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
           die('Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage());
         }

         $query=array();
         $cursor=$collection->find($query);


         foreach($cursor as $doc){
             echo $doc['comments'];
         }



    ?>
```

so when i use this code i have this error :

> Array to string conversion in line 86, its this line

`echo $doc['comments'];`

thanks with the help

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as the error says - you're trying to print out an array, and `echo` can print only scalars (int, string, float, etc).

To just quickly display the array, you could use `var_dump()`, but this should not be used in production. Instead, you could iterate over the comments like this:

```
foreach($cursor as $doc)
{
    foreach($docs['comments'] as $comment)
    {
        echo '"' . $comment['comment'] .'" by ' . $comment['user'];
    }
}
```